# im using an if statment to create a language setting using an input function but it isnt working as i intended? language python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

im making a class project where i have to create a rock paper scissors game and to get creative i decided to input a language setting for the 2 languages i speak. but when i input anything other than english it just prints it

the fallowing is the code i tried using a boolen but it just broke entierly
import random

```
import random

print("what is the language you choose to use english or irish?, cén teanga a labhraíonn tú? gaeilge no bearla?")
leabhar = input()

if leabhar == "english":
    #the fallowing code propts the user to choose
    print("options rock, paper,scissors")
    playersChoice = input("you choose: ")
    #the fallowing array is used to determen actions by both the CPU and the players
    actions = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    CPU = random.choice(actions)
    #the fallowing code allows the user to see both choices
    print(f"\n{playersChoice} vs {CPU} \n")
    if leabhar == "gaeilge":
        print("go raibh maith agat")
        #the fallowing code propts the user to choose
        print("options rock, paper,scissors")
        playersChoice = input("please choose: ")
        #the fallowing array is used to determen actions by both the CPU and the players
        actions = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
        CPU = random.choice(actions)
        #the fallowing code allows the user to see both choices
        print(f"\n{playersChoice} vs {CPU} \n")
```

Comment: First of all your indenting is incorrect. `if leabhar == "gaeilge"` will not happen if it's inside the `if leabhar == "english":` clause.

Comment: Also suggestion for cleaning the code: Put all the sentences into a dictionary and pick based on language. That way you don't need to write same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested your `if`s which isn't what you're expecting.

```
import random

print("what is the language you choose to use english or irish?, cén teanga a labhraíonn tú? gaeilge no bearla?").strip().lower()
leabhar = input()

if leabhar == "english":
    #the following code prompts the user to choose
    print("options rock, paper,scissors")
    playersChoice = input("you choose: ").strip().lower()
    #the following array is used to determine actions by both the CPU and the players
    actions = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    CPU = random.choice(actions)
    #the following code allows the user to see both choices
    print(f"\n{playersChoice} vs {CPU} \n")

elif leabhar == "gaeilge":
    print("go raibh maith agat")
    #the following code prompts the user to choose
    print("options rock, paper,scissors")
    playersChoice = input("please choose: ").strip().lower()
    #the following array is used to determine actions by both the CPU and the players
    actions = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    CPU = random.choice(actions)
    #the following code allows the user to see both choices
    print(f"\n{playersChoice} vs {CPU} \n")
```